# Kotlin file in buildSrc can not use Java class?

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin

update:
I put a demo in Github: [TestBuildSrc](https://github.com/RainFool/TestBuildSrc), It only has one Kotlin file and one java file under buildSrc folder.Occur same error(Test is a java class):

```
 Unresolved reference: Test
```

---

Old question:
I need an R2 file ,so I copy JakeWharton's [butterknife-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) in my buildSrc dir.

Weirdly，It's happen some error when I call Java class in Kotlin file:

```
> Task :buildSrc:compileKotlin FAILED
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath have the version 1.1, which is older than the API version 1.3. Consider using the runtime of version 1.3, or pass '-api-version 1.1' explicitly to restrict the available APIs to the runtime of version 1.1. You can also pass '-language-version 1.1' instead, which will restrict not only the APIs to the specified version, but also the language features
w: /Users/rainfool/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.1.3-2/2104f139db2a2d230c529b004c34a0993c4c2f19/kotlin-reflect-1.1.3-2.jar: Runtime JAR file has version 1.1 which is older than required for API version 1.3
w: /Users/rainfool/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.1.3-2/9b44c139a4ec57031e0c84ba0e49ba16df6d801c/kotlin-stdlib-1.1.3-2.jar: Runtime JAR file has version 1.1 which is older than required for API version 1.3
e: /Users/rainfool/WorkSpaceGitHuya/ViewComponent/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/RLibPlugin.kt: (4, 47): Unresolved reference: Test
e: /Users/rainfool/WorkSpaceGitHuya/ViewComponent/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/RLibPlugin.kt: (84, 29): Unresolved reference: Test
e: /Users/rainfool/WorkSpaceGitHuya/ViewComponent/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/com.duowan.viewcomponent.plugin/rfinal/Drive.kt: (11, 9): Unresolved reference: Test
e: /Users/rainfool/WorkSpaceGitHuya/ViewComponent/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/com.duowan.viewcomponent.plugin/rfinal/RLibPlugin.kt: (84, 29): Unresolved reference: FinalRClassBuilder
e: /Users/rainfool/WorkSpaceGitHuya/ViewComponent/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/com.duowan.viewcomponent.plugin/rfinal/RLibPlugin.kt: (85, 29): Unresolved reference: Test

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

The Test or FinalRClassBuilder are Java class.
My gradle file under buildSrc folder(modify source set block is not work):

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: "groovy"
...

sourceSets {
    main {
//        groovy {
//            srcDir 'src/main/java'
//        }

        kotlin {
//            srcDir 'src/main/java'
            srcDir 'src/main/kotlin'
        }

        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
        }

        resources {
            srcDir 'src/main/resources'
        }
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
targetCompatibility = "1.8"
```

What happend here?

Comment: By default, Kotlin source files can be in `java` or `kotlin` folder. Try placing `.kt` files in the `java` folder along with `.java` files.
It looks like you follow the standard paths convention, so the `sourceSets` configuration is not needed at all

Comment: I tried both way to build, they compile kotlin error in same reason:  
Unresolved reference: Test